# Limit of real logarithm

Tags: calculus, limits

During my homework, I've got to the following exercise:

Calculate the following limit (if exists):
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\ln\big(\cos(x)\big)}{x^2}\right).$$

I looked in the Calculus book to find an identity that will help me resolve the expression, and what I found was:

$$\frac{1}{n}\ln(n) = \ln(\sqrt[n]n)$$

I couldn't manage to prove that Identity and thus couldn't solve the question.
So what I need is:

1. Proof to the identity,
2. Help in solving the question.

Context:
Didn't learn either L'Hopital, McLauren or Taylor Series yet.
This question came just after the "Continuity" chapter.

Comment: Considering that you've now received three answers that use Taylor series, which you apparently haven't learned yet, please consider why adding *context* to your problem is important. That way, several people won't spend time writing answers that are not appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: i've added De L'hospital approach .. check my answer

Comment: The kind of intuition you need to nurture with these problems is the ability to unpack the expressions one function at a time, and to imagine *zooming in* on the limit point. So $\cos(x)$, that's gonna be tending towards $1$. Now zoom into the graph of the logarithm at $x=1$. It looks like a straight line with slope one, in other words, for $x$ close to one, we basically have $\ln x = x - 1$. So the numerator's pretty much just $\cos x - 1$. And so on.

Comment: Well the identity is just a consequence of the properties of the logarithm: you have $\ln(n) = \ln(\sqrt[n]{n} \sqrt[n]{n} \cdots \sqrt[n]{n}) = n\ln(\sqrt[n]{n})$ thus dividing both sides by $n$ we get $ln(\sqrt[n]{n}) = \frac1n \ln(n) $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use:
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u} = 1$$
(which can be easily proven by considering the function $u\mapsto \ln(1+u)$, and showing that it is differentiable at $0$ with derivative equal to $1$)
*and*
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u} = 1$$
which also can be shown the same way $\sin^\prime 0 = \cos 0 = 1$), 
then you have that, for $x\in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})\setminus\{0\}$:

$$
\frac{\ln\cos x}{x^2} = \frac{\ln \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln(1-\sin^2 x)}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln(1-\sin^2 x)}{-\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}. 
$$

Using the above, since $\sin^2 x\xrightarrow[x\to0]{} 0$ , you get, as all limits exist:
$$
\frac{\ln\cos x}{x^2} \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} -\frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Note that the first step, showing that $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u} = 1$, is equivalent to a Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+u)$ to order $1$. But it only uses elementary calculus, and does not rely on even knowing what a Taylor expansion is.

Comment: Fantastic answer! In my opinion, this is more elegant than using taylor series and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you. I know derivatives so I can understand your answer. But I didn't learn in yet so I can't use it in my homework

Answer (score 4):

Use *Taylor's formula* at order  $2$ and *equivalents*:

- $\cos x=1-\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$
- $\ln(1-u)\sim_0 -u$, hence $\ln(\cos x)\sim_0 -\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)\sim_0 -\dfrac{x^2}2$.

From this, we deduce
$$\frac{\ln\cos x}{x^2}\sim_0 -\frac{x^2}{2x^2}=-\frac12.$$

Without *Taylor's formula:*

You can prove directly that $\;\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x }{x^2(1+ \cos x)}=\frac12$, so that
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\sim_0\frac12,\quad\text{whence}\quad \cos x\sim_0 1 - \dfrac{x^2}2.$$

Comment: I can't use it because I didn't learn it yet

Comment: Which is first: L'Hospital rule or Taylor expsansion?

Comment: You didn't learn what?

Comment: They Taylor's formula. This question came right after the Continuity chapter.

Comment: Then, in any case keep that in mind for when you will -- it's never lost.

Comment: @CodeNinja: I added a way without Taylor, using only some trigonometry and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$.

Comment: what is the ~ sign?

Comment: It means ["equivalent."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) If $g$ does not cancel, then $f\sim_0g$ means $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} 1$.

Comment: @Bernard The very last step (when using equivalents) and very last part of the first line are misleading: with equivalents, only the first non-zero term matters... for instance, $\cos x\sim_{x\to0} 1-\frac{1}{\ln\ln\ln x}$ as well.

Comment: @Clement C. Yes, you're right I went too fast. It's a rather subtle error, I must say. I've corrected my answer, and hopefully, it's correct (*bis repetita*…) now. Thanks for pointing the error!

Comment: No worries!  ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this question:

- have you heard about [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)? By applying McLaurin rules you get
  $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + O(x^4)\right)}{x^2}\\=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2!} + O(x^2)}{x^2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2 \cdot \left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{O(x^2)}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{O(x^2)}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
- another approach is using [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):
  differentiate both numerator and denominator (given you checkes the hypothesis) and you get
  $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot -\sin x}{2x}$$ and since $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ you can simplify to get
  $$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot -\sin x}{2x} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}-\frac{1}{2 \cos x} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
- classic approach is to check the limit by its definition: let $f(x) = \frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}$, what you want to check is that for every number $\epsilon$ there is some number $\delta$ such that
  $$|f(x) - \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) | < \epsilon$$
  whenever $| x - 0| < \delta$

Comment: But this is another question.

Comment: Yu can apply L'Hospital rule.

Comment: what you can use?

Comment: Can you elaborate about the last "classic" approach?

Comment: Classic approach is wrong...  one that's the derivative, two it's misleading to just restate the question and call that the "classic approach" next to two actual approaches.

Comment: sorry, edited correctly

Answer (score 1):

Use the well-known Taylor series 
$$\cos(x)= 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4+O(x^6)$$
$$\ln(1+x)= x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{5}x^5+O(x^6)$$
to get 
$$\ln(\cos(x))=-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{12}x^4+O(x^6)$$
Can you continue?

Comment: FWIW: no need to go as far as order $4$ (which looks a tad scary at first).